# Referencing a cell value as a parameter in the URL in Excel's Data From Web function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, excel-web-query

Hi I'm trying to get some data from a website into a worksheet using Excel's Data -> From Web function. But I want the parameter of the url to be dynamic and reference that value from a cell in the worksheet. I'm attaching a screenshot too. Could someone tell me how to reference the cell value under URL parts? Any help would be much appreciated. [Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hdme.png)

Comment: There is a function `=WEBSERVICE()` which requires a URL as input, e.g. `=WEBSERVICE("abc.bla")`. Check out the ms support description here: [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/webservice-function-0546a35a-ecc6-4739-aed7-c0b7ce1562c4?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60644&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: @DattelKlauber thank you, is there any way I can add a parameter as a part in the Data ->From Web function? Like abc.com/query?q=CELLVALUE It is much easier for me to use as it makes sorting and formatting the data very easy. The webservice function returns the whole page which I have to format manually :)

Comment: You can concatenate strings with the `&` symbol. Here is an example for retrieving data from a csv file on this [website](http://gpi.tge.pl/en/generacja): [Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJlde.png). As you can see in the screenshot, the output comes as one long string in csv format and is not very useful, but it works as an example.

Comment: Meaning for your example, you may be able to use `=WEBSERVICE("abc.com/query?q="&A1)` given that the CELLVALUE is in A1. However, I don't know if the format of the data that you are referencing with the URL is eligible for the function.

Answer (score 2):

Name the cell with the parameter - say call it URLParameter. Then set up your query with a static value, open the editor and switch to the advanced editor. After the initial `Let` add a new step that looks like:

```
URLPart = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="URLParameter"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
```

Then amend the Web.Contents part of your source to add in the parameter - for example:

```
Web.Contents("www.blah.com/" & URLPart)
```

Comment: Hi Rory, it's not clear to me what you mean by query as I'm not using any code. I'm just using the From Web function under the Data tab. Could you explain this in a bit more detail?

Comment: That is Power Query, which uses M code, like the part I posted above. After selecting the URL you should click Edit instead of Load, then on the View tab click Advanced Editor. You should then see the M code.